# Проблема с NetBeans. В коде вместо '\' показывает 'y'

Tags: java, netbeans, шрифты

1.У меня в коде вместо "\" показывает "y" [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По первому вопросу  не совсем понятно, что Вы имеете ввиду: экранирование или неверная кодировка, и добавьте код, что хотите сделать. Если экранирование, то попробуйте вместо "\" писать `"\\"`, т.к. обратный слэш необходимо экранировать обратным слэшем.По второму вопросу да, принцип такой же.

Comment: @MrFylypenko я когда пишу код в NetBeans вместо \ (не помню обр или просто слэш) пишется y.
Т.е. хочу написать \n а пишется yn

Comment: здесь у человека была похожая проблема (http://w.planetnetbeans.org/topic28620.html) решилось заменой шрифта Tools->Options->Fonts&Colors->Syntax->Default.

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov Вспомнил!!! Я же изменял шрифт в NetBeans! Поменяю на другой.
Спасибо!

Comment: дополните ответ с названием шрифта до и после, может быть данный вопрос будет полезен не только вам но и кому то еще

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была решена заменой шрифта в настройках NetBeans на шрифт по умолчанию.
P.S.Проблемный шрифт был "...Gothic...".

Comment: А какой шрифт вызывал эту проблему?

Comment: @gil9red либо YU Gothic либо MS Gothic, уже не помню.